# Meaning of Russian phrase "как ходит за кошкою кошка"

Tags: перевод, phrase

I'm trying to understand this section from a humorous song.

> ... бабушка Света 
>   Пьёт кофе с морошкой, 
>   Любуясь в окошко, 
>   Как ходит за кошкою кошка.

Based on my limited knowledge of Russian, and some help from Google translate, a literal translation would be:

> ... grandmother Sveta 
>   Drinks coffe with cloudberries, 
>   Admiring in the little window 
>   How a cat walks for a cat

I don't really understand what the last line means.  Is this idiomatic?

Comment: @shabunc I'm not sure why you closed this question.  This wasn't a "please translate this for me" question; I gave my own attempt at a translation and explained where I was having difficulty.  It's true that I'm only a beginning student of Russian but I don't understand what more prior research I could possibly have done to improve this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not an idiom, the meaning is straightforward

> Любуясь в окошко,
>   Как ходит за кошкою кошка.
>
> Watching through the window
>    how the cats walk (pass by) one after the other

Comment: I see, "кошка за кошкою" ≈ "cat by cat".  Thanks!

Comment: This, however, can also be translated as "cat courting (stalking) another cat".

Comment: @Alexander don't think so, i gave an answer after reading the entire lyrics, in the context the meaning is quite obvious and unequivocal